# createrepo -v --update folder failed in incremental build in docker

Tags: linux, centos, python

### env description:

root@sriov-TaiShan-200:~# docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           20.10.17
Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          20.10.17
[root@e115d0727d6b /]# createrepo --version
createrepo 0.9.9

### problem description:

1. build docker image with below Dockerfile with command `docker run --rm -it test:test bash`

```
FROM arm64v8/centos:7.9.2009
RUN curl http://mirrors.aliyun.com/repo/Centos-altarch-7.repo -o /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo; yum update -y; yum install createrepo rpmdevtools -y;
RUN echo -e $'[local] \n\
name=Local Yum \n\
baseurl=file:///root/rpmbuild \n\
gpgcheck=0 \n\
enabled=1' > /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
RUN cd /root; rpmdev-setuptree; createrepo -v /root/rpmbuild
```

2. start a container with `docker run --rm -it test:test bash`
3. run below command then you got error

```
[root@dd0710d5ea50 /]# createrepo -v --update /root/rpmbuild
Scanning old repo data
Saving Primary metadata
Saving file lists metadata
Saving other metadata
Generating sqlite DBs
Starting other db creation: Thu Jul 13 00:38:36 2023
Ending other db creation: Thu Jul 13 00:38:36 2023
Starting filelists db creation: Thu Jul 13 00:38:36 2023
Ending filelists db creation: Thu Jul 13 00:38:36 2023
Starting primary db creation: Thu Jul 13 00:38:36 2023
Ending primary db creation: Thu Jul 13 00:38:36 2023
Sqlite DBs complete
Error moving final /root/rpmbuild/repodata to old dir /root/rpmbuild/.olddata
```

Comment: find something related https://lore.kernel.org/all/CAEuZuT+K=T_HED0UT3h4PeHa3DLwrA_jQWg9w+SnKy2mNReLag@mail.gmail.com/

Comment: May be we can report a bug to http://createrepo.baseurl.org/